# a way to copy a 2dimensional array into a struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have this array filled up with characters in my maze.c file:

char normalMazeArray[6][12]; dynamically filled as mazeArray[row][column]

Now I want to pass what the array to the mazeArray that is located in my struct (maze.h)

my struct is called:

```
typedef struct {
    char mazeArray;
} maze_t;
```

I have tried copying it as follows:

```
maze_t* maze;

char normalMazeArray[6][12]; // filled with info

typedef struct {
    char mazeArray;
} maze_t;

maze->mazeArray = normalMazeArray;
```

however it is not working, 
anyone who could help me?

Comment: Of which type "mazeArray" is? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: mazeArray is of type char, i have editted it. I want to transfer the contents of the normalMazeArray to maze.mazeArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing what you're trying to do is not exactly possible. There are two slightly different solutions you can use, though.

`normalMazeArray` is of type `char [6][12]` - it's an array. You can either copy its contents to the same type of array using `memcpy()`:

```
typedef struct {
    char mazeArray[6][12];
} maze_t;

memcpy(maze->mazeArray, normalMazeArray, sizeof(normalMazeArray));
```

or if your `normalMazeArray` persists throughout the lifetime of the program, you can assign a pointer to it in the structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char (*mazeArray)[12];
} maze_t;

maze->mazeArray = normalMazeArray;
```

Answer (score -1):

Wait, how??

First of all, `maze` is a pointer, so you can't have `maze.mazeArray`. Second of all, `maze->mazeArray` is of type char, while `mazeArray` is of type `char**`. No can do.

You should write a function which allocates `char**` array, and then strdups strings from `mazeArray`. Or, if you want ownership transfer, and not just copy, you could go like this:

```
typedef struct {
   char** mazeArray;
} maze_t;
maze_t maze;
maze.mazeArray = mazeArray;
```

Comment: "while mazeArray is of type `char**`" - No, it isn't. It's of type `char [6][12]`.